# Flashing Google Coral board from SD Card fails with error: Wrong image format for "source" command

Tags: sd-card, google-coral

Flashing a [coral dev board](https://coral.ai/products/dev-board) per the [getting started guide](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/#flash-the-board) results in the the error `Wrong image format for "source" command`. This error is what is displayed in the serial console when the SD card is inserted in the board and the board is powered up - full output below. I didn't find any documentation for this problem so I am posting it here in case anyone else has this issue.

```
U-Boot SPL 2019.04.1 (Apr 29 2020 - 18:40:05 +0000)
power_bd71837_init
Board id: 2
DDRINFO: start DRAM init
DDRINFO:ddrphy calibration done
DDRINFO: ddrmix config done
Normal Boot
Trying to boot from MMC2
hdr read sector 300, count=1


U-Boot 2019.04.1 (Apr 29 2020 - 18:40:05 +0000), Build: jenkins-enterprise.uboot-imx-1

CPU:   Freescale i.MX8MQ rev2.0 1500 MHz (running at 1000 MHz)
CPU:   Commercial temperature grade (0C to 95C) at 33C
Reset cause: POR
Model: Freescale i.MX8MQ Phanbell
DRAM:  1 GiB
MMC:   FSL_SDHC: 0, FSL_SDHC: 1
Loading Environment from MMC... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial

 BuildInfo:
  - ATF
  - U-Boot 2019.04.1

flash target is MMC:0
Net:
Error: ethernet@30be0000 address not set.

Error: ethernet@30be0000 address not set.
eth-1: ethernet@30be0000
Fastboot: Normal
Normal Boot
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
** No partition table - mmc 1 **
## Executing script at 40480000
Wrong image format for "source" command
## Starting auxiliary core at 0x00000000 ...
u-boot=>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error results from a bad SD card, or perhaps one that has already been used (formatted) for other uses. I was able to bypass this error and successfully install the OS by burning the image per the the [getting started guide](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/#flash-the-board) on a **brand new SD card** (I used a Samsung 128GB Pro Endurance card). I used [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) on a mac, which burns the image in just a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

For work I've had to provision dozens of these and they are super finicky about sd cards. I've bought 4 brand new completely identical (same brand, size, etc.) sd cards and burn them all identically. 1 will work on one board but not another, another will work in the 2nd but not the first, etc. So the only advice I have is "keep trying".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers from Oliver and j2abro. I just dug the Coral Dev Board out of my project drawer and started trying to get it running.

First of all, make sure you read the directions and set the DIP switches properly (this dip, me, didn't do that, at first). I finally got it to work, but Oliver's answer seems to match my experience (Dev Board is finicky about SD Cards). Here's the cards used and result. All flashed with BalenaEtcher on a MacBook Pro (M1 2020, Monterrey 12.6):

1. SanDisk UltraPlus 256GB (multiple FAILS: didn't set DIPs correctly. derp!)
2. SanDisk UltraPlus 32GB #1 (FAILED with DIPs correctly set: same result as OP)
3. SanDisk UltraPlus 32GB #2 (FAILED with DIPs correctly set: same result as OP)
4. SanDisk UltraPlus 256GB (SUCCESS: set DIPs correctly) same card as #1

All these cards were brand new, right out of the retail packaging; nothing else was written to them before the Coral Dev Board image.

**Theory:** I tried the 32GB cards thinking that this board might have a problem with exFAT (above 32GB) storage formatting, similar to the Raspberry Pi boot limitation. However, given my and j2abro's success with larger SD Cards, I'd recommend trying a larger SD Card (more than 32GB) rather than the typical 32GB or less you'd use for a Pi. Seems like the Dev Board *likes* exFAT formatting better?

**Tip:** I strongly recommend connecting to the board using the Serial Console while setting up the board (link below), otherwise you'll be doing a lot of guessing as to what's going on with the setup and waste your time:
https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/serial-console/

Here's what I saw (finally) in the Serial Console after the second reboot after a successful flash with the 256GB card:

```
...
[    8.788556] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): usb1: link is not ready

Mendel GNU/Linux (eagle) lime-jet ttymxc0

lime-jet login:
```

Hope this helps you get to a successful setup.